# If statement check seems to not work properly

Tags: java

So I have this block of code:

```
public Student(String name, String subject) {
        if(subject.substring(17,18) == "e"){
            subjectName = "English";
        }else if(subject.substring(17,18) == "m") {
            subjectName = "Math";
        }
        studentName = name;
    }
```

I am feeding the Student in a name as a string and then a subject which is in a form like this:

```
..\text\students\english\grades
```

Now I use substring on it and get only the first letter of the subject. If the letter is e then the lesson name is english and so on.

But for some reason my IF checks dont pass at all, if I throw a sysout in them, nothing happens, the check never passes while it should...

What could be the problem here?

Comment: It would make more sense to split at the `\\ ` and use `startsWith()` for the correct index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing `String` using `==`, you need to use `.equals()` method for `String`

Try to change your code to something like this:

```
if(subject.substring(17,18).equals("e")){
        subjectName = "English";
    }else if(subject.substring(17,18).equals("m")) {
        subjectName = "Math";
    }
```

Comment: Missing a few parentheses.